# getting undefined variables when using session

Tags: php, session, variables

I get an undefiend variable error when i call another `$_SESSION` but when i remove this piece of code it shows no errors, I am using `$_SESSION` in order to pass one variable to another php script, can anyone enlighten me on what may be causing this issue?

I know the variable is defiened but for some reason calling a `$_SESSION` causes this error?

```
<div>
    <? 
    if(empty($item_details['trucks'])) {
        include_once ('trucks.php');
        $_SESSION['runmapapi'] = 'start'; 
        //$runmapapi == true;
        echo '<p> Success</p></div>'; 
    } else {
        echo '<p>failed</p></div>';
    } 
    ?>
<div>
    <p>Cars</p>
</div>  
</div>
</div></body>
<? } ?>
<? } ?>   
<?= $print_footer; ?>
```

Comment: Undefined variable i edited my post to include the code, should i post the include php file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using session variable, you have to initialize the session by using

`session_start();`

so wherever you use any of the session variable in your page, make sure you first declare the `session_start()`

so  in your page it should be

```
//initialize session to use session variable
session_start();
include_once ('trucks.php');
$_SESSION['runmapapi'] = 'start';
```

Comment: hi Ibrahim i have the session_start bit in my included trucks.php file

Comment: the error states that you have not initialized the session. can you post the code from trucks.php

Comment: hello Ibrahim thanks for your quick response, i have just commented out that line so that error no longer exists, i will vote for your response for your great help